# Where to get/ download SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.Viewer.dll

Tags: wpf, crystal-reports, report

I want to generate Crystal Reports in WPF.
I am missing assembly reference SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.Viewer.dll and SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.ViewerShared.dll.

However, I do not know where I can get them and Add Reference into my application.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just Download Crystal Report Runtime
This ddl are include in runtime
[Download](http://download.cnet.com/1770-20_4-0.html?query=crystal+report+10&searchtype=downloads)

And Add Reference in WPF Application  if you want to deploy this application then you must install this Crystal Report Runtime in client pc  in order to run application without getting any error…

Answer (score 0):

you can download WPF viewer  from [here](http://www.businessobjects.com/forms/crystalreports/viewer/).

Answer (score 0):

I am using the version "SP 33" of "Crystal Reports" with Visual Studio 2022,

I found the SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.Viewer.dll and SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.ViewerShared.dll, in the following path:

C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win64_x64\dotnet